# How to get fast ajax response for images

Tags: php, ajax, image, jquery, optimization

I have a big database to get dynamically images from Ajax response.
How could i make it lightning fast

images is in comma separated form such as

**img4.jpg, img3.jpg, img5.jpg, img7.jpg,img11.jpg, img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg, img6.jpg, img8.jpg**

my code for php.

```
function childImgsGrid(){

        $parentImgId = $_POST['parentImgId'];

        $query = mysql_query("select child_imgs_id,child_imgs from parent where parent_img_id = $parentImgId") 
                or die(mysql_error());

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $arrayOfImages = explode(",", $result['child_imgs']);
        $i=1;
        foreach($arrayOfImages as $nameOfImage){

            echo "<li><a href='#lookbook' ><div class='view'><img src='images/slide/".$nameOfImage."'></a></li>";

        }
    }
```

and for Ajax

```
var parentImgId = $anchor.attr("id");

                var dataString = 'queryString=childImgsGrid'+'&parentImgId='+parentImgId; 

                var arrayOfImages = new Array();

                $glob.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajaxtemplate.php",
                    data: dataString,                   
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        $glob('#grid').html(response);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: That depends. Which part of your current code is slow?

Comment: I edited my question and also posted script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very broad topic in general but I'll attempt to throw some light on the matter.

1. Optimized versions of Images

   Like Facebook, when images are added you can use a background job to create a low-quality version of the image. When the image is requested, this low-quality image is show while the original high quality image is loaded in the background. Once done loading, just replace.
2. Pre-loading

   If you know or have an idea of what images will need to be shown (common case in galleries to pre-load the next 2 or 3 images) you can fetch them without user input. So when a user opens image #443 you load it along with #444, #445 in the background.
3. Using in-memory stores

   If the database records are very large, and presuming you are saving images in the filesystem not as blobs in the DB, and the retrival is based on a unique key (primary or otherwise) you can implement something like memcache or redis so that the quering is very fast.
4. Node.js

   If the number of requests for images is becoming very high, think about using an asynchronous server response architecture like node.js.

The particular use-case as well as technologies will change the implementation of each of the above but the overall concepts should be solid.

Comment: @NareshKumar I know you see that I am Indian, but SO is English only and for good reason. Edit / remove the Hindi comment before someone down-votes it!

Comment: @VarunVohra, Valid point, but one can't downvote comments on SO. OP, Please use English in SO, its not a site catering to only us Indians..

Comment: Ok.sir. i mean to say its not bore for me. and i will learn from you all.